# django admin queryset display related objects in a field

Tags: django

```
def Ark():
    li = Forti.objects.all(), Autre.objects.all()
    list1=list(li)
    return list1
class License(models.Model):
    assigne_a = models.CharField(default =Ark, max_length=25, 
                 verbose_name="assigné à l'equipement")
    categorie = models.TextField( max_length=15, choices=Cat_choice, 
                 verbose_name='Categorie generale', blank=True)
    cate = models.TextField( max_length=15, choices=Cat2_choice, 
                 verbose_name='Categorie Interne', blank=True)
    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'License'
```

i want it to display related object in the field assigne_a in sort of list but it is diplaying it like this:

```
[<QuerySet [<Forti: DR 60 E>, <Forti: DR 60 D>]>, <QuerySet []>]
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. `assigne_a` is a CharField, but `Ark` returns a list of querysets. Why? What are you trying to put in that field?

Comment: "i am new in programming", i want to display a list of object like like a dropdown